# .net core service in kubernetes yields slower performance than development machine

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, azure-aks

I have a service written in c# .net core 5 that yields responses that are 2 times slower when running in Kubernetes compare to running in my local development machine.  On the latter, I get a consistent response time of 2 seconds, whereas the same service running in Kubernetes responds in 4 seconds consistently.  I tried increasing the request/limit resources for my Kubernetes deployment to 2 CPUs and 2 GB of memory just to see if it will make any difference to no avail.  Also, when I analyze the resources being used by the pod running that service it is very low.  It is as if it is not taking advantage of the resource allocated to it.

The service is running on Azure Kubernetes Service 1.18.14.

Thanks in advance for any insight.